# AWS CodePipeline Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I keep getting a permissions error with Codepipeline, even though I've setup IAM roles for this service which should provide access to all other services in AWS

`The provided role does not have permissions to perform this action. Underlying error: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 955B6F56EC90A2F0; S3 Extended Request ID: +UJm0N7mWrw0zFkY2kM/y91YxY50zX4xulyBXgZeNw9PSdzyCZH3d95YDxRFNJvH5XNfcdFYI2g=)`

IAM Roles
[image]

I can't find any resources online anywhere for this error code.

Comment: Where are you seeing that error? In a failed CodePipeline action? What type of action is it? It might also be worth double checking the pipeline is using that role by calling aws codepipeline get-pipeline from the CLI.

Comment: As a side note. If you really wanna make your life easier when it comes to roles and rights, use AWS CDK. Getting a codepipeline up and running with all kinds of integrations like S3 or ECR is really so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

In order to troubleshoot please check this things:

1. Lets the permissions over the codepipeline buckets that it has for default codepipeline-us-east-1-XXXXXX
2. Lets  Lets the permissions over the codepipeline buckets that is specify in the codebuild if you are using to store the artifacts.
3. Check the flow of the artifacts inside the flow and check the outputs of each stage and the incomming for the following ones.
4. Please check that you are using 2 different roles in the codepipeline flow, one of them is the role for the codepipeline and another one is the codebuild role, so check if those roles has permissions over the buckets and the bucket policy allow this roles to put files on it.